# I want to reform this text

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I want to tranform below text from `01   j   dh   sish  kdh   sh j   dhd`  to `01 j dh sish kdh sh j dhd`

```
const reformText = '01    j    dh   sish  kdh          sh j   dhd     h  '

function textTransformer(text) {
if (!Array.isArray(text)) {

    let text2Arr = text.trim().split(' ')
    let pushArr = []
    let finalResult;

    text2Arr.map(function (item) {
        if (item.length !== 0) {
            pushArr.push(item)
        }
        finalResult = pushArr.join().replaceAll(',', '')
    })
    console.log(finalResult)
} else {
    alert('Your DATA STRUCTURE is An ARRAY')
}
}

textTransformer(reformText)
```

Comment: This is a good use for regexs: replace `\s+` (= a sequence of one or more whitespace characters) with a single space.

Comment: That solution seems quite complicated, is there some reason for that approach? If you're just removing excess spaces, `text.trim().replace(/ +/g, " ")` would do the job (for spaces, use `\s` instead of a space for all whitespace). (Well, `text.trim().replace(/ {2,}/g, " ")` would probably be better.)

Comment: `reformText.replace(/\s{2,}/g, " ")`

Comment: Also, `map` is not just an iterator. Don't use `map` if you aren't using the array it creates. Details in [this post](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/04/17/misusing-map/) on my blog.

Comment: Also if you're going to join an array with spaces you can just use `.join(' ')` rather than joining with commas then changing the commas to spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you really want to complicate things, why not use a reducer?

```js
const txt = "01    j    dh   sish  kdh          sh j   dhd     h  ";

const cleaned = txt
  .trim()
  .split("")
  .reduce( (acc, val) => 
    /\s{2,}/.test(`${acc[acc.length-1]+val}`) ? acc : [...acc, val],  [])
  .join("");

console.log(`[${cleaned}]`);

// for the record
console.log(`[${txt.trim().replace(/\s+/g, " ")}]`);
```